# Implementing Server-Sent Events into Intel XDK

Tags: javascript, html, hybrid-mobile-app, server-sent-events, intel-xdk

I was wondering if it is possible to use SSE's in hybrid apps? When opened over a mobile browser it works, but I am failing in implementing them into apps. What am I missing? I have the feeling of not getting something right..

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://caniuse.com/#feat=eventsource  shows you can use them on iOS 7.1 and above.  On Android, they are only available on Android 4.4+.  Which device/OS are you testing on?  If you are on Android, try building for Crosswalk.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am testing on iOS 7.2 and like I said the Problem is not to open SSE in the Browser but to implement it into an app. And you are saying that it should be possible in an app, too, right?

Comment: in theory, yes.  If you post a sample somewhere, I can try to help debug it.

Comment: Ok, Problem solved. I had to change the EventSource. That's the part which was different from the website. Because I had to say him to listen to the full adress. Silly me. Thanks anyway for your time!